# Sum of S|C Formula?

Tags: probability

I have a formula like that:

${ \sum_{s} P(S=s|C=c)} $

I don't know what does it mean?

**i.e.** P(S|C)+P(~S|C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the sum is over all possible configurations of random variable S.

It should evaluate to 1.